# TinyMCE strips out audio tag

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE and I'm using the Full HTML format which shouldn't strip any tags. I copy another web page with an html5 audio tag in it and paste it into the editor. I can see the html5 audio player there, but when I save, it is stripped out.

I tried again and this time brought up the raw html editor and directly put the audio tag into the html. When I click Update, the audio tag is stripped out.

Here is my Full HTML text format config:

[image]

Comment: Did you recently update TinyMCE? There is a [bug report](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4398) about `<audio>` tags being removed, but it has been closed. The [TinyMCE demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) doesn't strip them out.

Comment: I downloaded TinyMCE 2 days ago, so unless there was a new release today, then I'm up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deselect "Verify HTML" in the configuration page for the input format using Wysiwyg. Those settings are available in admin/config/content/wysiwyg.

[image: screenshot]

Once I disabled that option, I tried with the following HTML, and it worked.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

[image: option disabled]

With that option enabled, this is what I get right after entering the HTML with the HTML button.

[image: option enabled]